# Invariant subspace vs. irreducible subspace (terminology)

Tags: terminology, representation-theory

In a course in representation theory I was presented the following proposition:

Let $(\pi,V)$ be a finite dimensional irreducible representation with a cyclic vector.

1. $V$ has a unique max. proper sub representation $W$.
2. $V$ has a unique non-trivial irreducible quotient, namely $V/W$

How to understand "irreducible quotient"?

Comment: It means that there is a unique submodule $W$ of $V$ such that the quotient $V/W$ is irreducible. For any $W\subset V$, the irreducibility of $V/W$ is equivalent to $W$ being a maximal submdule of $V$, so (1) and (2) are equivalent for any module $V$.

Comment: Something is wrong with your theorem statement.  An irreducible representation is one which has no subrepresentations.